# Why this occurs when I run ros2 topic list or ros2 --help in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ros2, px4, rviz

I have a ros2 container running (humble-ros-base-l4t-r36.2.0). I started it with `docker start -i <container_id>` and used `docker exec -it <container_id>` to open a new shell in `/bin/bash`.

I even sourced the humble ros2 and echoed this (`echo "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash" >>.bashrc`). I'm not sure why this is occurring.

`ros2 --help`:

[image: ros2 --help]

`ros2 topic list`:

[image: ros2 topic list]

Why is this taking place?

Comment: Check your env variables. It looks like you've added env vars to your container on initial start, but not when you exec'ed into the same container. You are running a separate copy of Bash for each terminal, and each will have its own env vars.